# Retrieving CSS properties in JavaScript and then modifying it

Tags: javascript, css

How can the CSS property of an element (e.g `margin-left`) be retrieved and then some value can be added to it, and the element gets altered with the updated value.

Suppose:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myElement");
var value = element.style.margin-left;

//How to do something like this?
var updatedValue = value + 10;
element.style.margin-left = updatedValue;
```

As, `style.margin-left` accepts values in pixels. How to retrieve the current value, then add something to it, then update the element with the same?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have option to use jQuery?

Comment: No. jQuery is out of this scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert the string to a number, then re-apply the `px`.

```
var value = parseInt(element.style.marginLeft);
element.style.marginLeft = (value + 10) + 'px';
```

Note: this will work for other units, such as `em`, `%`, etc.

Per @ScottKaye in the comments, here is an example using `getComputedStyle`, if the styles are applied via a stylesheet instead of in the `style` attribute on the DOM element:

```
var value = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle(element).marginLeft );
element.style.marginLeft = (value + 10) + 'px';
```

Comment: I'm getting a null value, when I'm trying to parse the margin.style.marginLeft

Comment: Is `margin.style.marginLeft` correct (i.e. is the variable named `margin`)?

Comment: @AnkitNeo Unless margin-left is set explicitly in the inline style, you can't get stylesheet values like this.  Take a look at [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) if this is what you need.

Comment: Good point @ScottKaye, I added an example using `getComputedStyle`.